# Brining the UISearch bar from any position: iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Im creating this app for the iPhone and what I want to do is bring up a hidden search bar from any position of a view when scrolling. I currently have it sitting on top of the view.

I want to be able to invoke the hidden search bar from any postion as the user scrolls. The search bar can ONLY be used from the top position as of right now. If any one can point me to the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting UISearchBar **above** your UIScrollView via *[view insertSubview:searchBar aboveSubview:scrollView]*. Then you can just call *[searchBar setHidden:NO]* and your search bar will appear on the screen.